# Incremental Users On Platform Method

Tags: classification, data-imputation, population-attributable-fraction

I have the following data (aggregated, user level data is not available).

date | platform | total_watch_time

platform = [mobile, mobile + desktop, mobile + desktop + tv]

I want to determine the total_watch_time that I can attribute to tv only.

The hard part is someone could co-view with a TV viewing e.g. 2 different users on a mobile could use the same TV; so we do not want to 'double count' the watch_time.

I remember reading a statistical methodology in a paper a while back that addressed this but I forgot the area / solution.

Comment: There isn't sufficient information to give a definite answer.  All you can achieve are the obvious bounds -- a simple mathematical problem.  To go further, you need data or strong assumptions or both.  What such additional information do you have?

Comment: I can split the data out further in the following way: the number of users (demographics i.e. age, gender), country, external metrics like reachable population / total population.

Comment: How would that be related to how often people co-view?

Comment: We have internal estimates of what co-viewing watchtime is but I think this doesn't help much solve the issue?